# Standard wordpress widgets

Tags: wordpress, templates, widget

I'm making wordpress template. When I install this template(on stock wordpress), in footer block appears 6 standard widgets(Search, Recent Posts, Recent Comments etc.). I need to make these widgets do not appear by default(after install WP).

I have 3 widgets block, but even if I change the name of footer widgets block, standard widgets still appears by default in footer block . Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Appearance -> Widgets there should be a list of widgets available on the left and widget blocks on the right. 
The "Search, Recent Posts, Recent Comments etc." should be in one of the blocks on the right.  You can either delete each widget individually or drag the widget onto the "Available Widget" section.

EDIT:

When creating pages you can set the "Template" to "Full-width Page Template, No Sidebar" which won't allow any widgets to be displayed. Or in the functions.php file remove the twentytwelve_widgets_init() function.

Comment: I do not mean that... I know how to remove widgets. I need not to display these widgets in my template by default(after user install template).
When user will install template, in footer block would be these widgets. I want to make footer block empty by default(after user install template)

Comment: no.. If I remove initialization of footer widget function, footer block will not be at all. Try to explain with example.

I have 3 widget blocks on mainpage. Two sidebar blocks and one footer.
I install stock wordpress. Then I install my template.
When I go to mainpage, I see 6 default widgets in footer block. And empty 2 sidebar widget blocks. I want, that the footer block will be empty too(had no widgets) like 2 sidebar blocks. I don't want to remove footer block at all. It needs to edit template code, not to change settings in wordpress. I hope you understand me :) Thanks